# Git / Mercurial : Separate repos in structure

Tags: git, frameworks, bitbucket, php

I am trying to get on the [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) / [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) train, and to that end, I am trying to make sense of the best way to manage my workflow so that I can create composer pacakges with my framework of choice and application but damned if I can sort out a way to do it with Git/Github or Hg/BitBucket (or both).

**Current Structure/Workflow**

```
%path%/sites/[framework]
 - contains up to date framework git repo  
%path%/sites/[framework]/application
 - contains app specific code and is a bitbucket repo
*%path%/www/[appname]_public
 - contains public files and is a bitbucket repo i.e. "public_html" folder
```

With properly aliasing, this works for my current sites *(each site is a separate folder in "/sites")*. And since I use two separate repo mechanisms, I can update the framework for that particular site whenever I want without it really hurting my application and vice versa.

Since the packages are contained as subfolders of the "application" folder (so I can create and test them), how can I "wrap" those folders as packages as separate repos so that I can provide them as standalone composer packages available on github or bitbucket? I am kind of at a loss.

```
%path%/sites/[framework]/application/[module]
 - contains controllers, models, views, etc... to be wrapped up as a composer
   "package" and made available on github or bitbucket as its own repo.
```

Perhaps someone here can give me a hand with the logic on this, or how to set it up, as I can't fathom how to do it. Is it possible? Am I over/under thinking the issue?

Maybe my whole way of thinking is wrong. With my existing structure I was trying to accomplish the task, but Git Submodules or HG nested repos don't seem to work the way I had anticipated.

Is my workflow seriously flawed or do I need more Git knowledge to accomplish this? Is there an easier / better way? I will happily rebuild my structure/workflow if I can keep the Framework / SiteApplicationCode / Packages as separate repos with some mechanism / logic I am missing.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%path%/sites/[framework]/application/[module] should be a git repository that you share with others by pushing it to some public (public to your company only if you want) location, say git.yourcompany.com .

Then, you may create a satis composer repository accessible at satis.company.com, that you will initialize with a json file referencing your public repositories. Make sure you a create composer.json file for each of your modules first, to make them composer-installable.

Then, reinstall your project using a composer.json file per application, that will fetch the desired modules at the desired version.
They will appear in %path%/sites/[framework]/application/vendor/ and an autoload file will be generated.

If your code can be published on github, you can skip the git+satis part and submit your modules to packagist.org

I may have misunderstood your structure, but I hope you get the idea

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't believe it addresses my problem, unless I missed something.

I have a read-only repo from github for the framework which I pull down with git. I have a normal repo at bitbucket for the app-specific code which is a subfolder of the framework repo. Now I wish to add the module folders as separate repos and they are subfolders of the app-specific code folder.

This way I keep the framework up to date and separate, the app-specific code up to date and separate. I was just hoping to get the modules separate as well but I am thinking this won't be possible.

Comment: If you can write a composer.json file in your bitbucket repo, then you can pull composer packages from packagist.org or from satis.yourcompany.com. These packages can be your modules.

Comment: Thanks greg0ire. I get what you are saying. I was trying to think of how to get those modules individually on github/bitbucket as well and tried to wrap your answer around my deluded thought process. Got what you are saying now. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you figured it out, it is indeed quite complicated!